# How can i make the real pixel in images to match the flutter pixel

Tags: flutter, dart

i have weird results that i want to understand .

1- i have image in my device gallery it's width 2448 , height 3264.

4- Out of curiosity, I wrote the following code

```
Container(
color:Colors.yellow,
width:2448 , // i know it is big width but it is the same image width
height:3264, // i know it is big height but it is the same image height 
)
```

5- the output of height and width was completely bigger than image height and width

Question : why it was bigger ? Isn't it the same height and width ?

then i relisted that flutter using physical pixel if i am not wrong , and image use logical pixel depend on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView/devicePixelRatio.html

so i decided to do the following

```
Container(
color:Colors.yellow,
width:2448/MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio
height:3264/MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio 
)
```

but it still not match the same image dimensions .

i was using the stack and the container is above the image on stack , this way i tested it and the container was covering all screen but the image height was like half screen

note: i don't care of UI and i can solve this . but i want understand this behavior

How can i make the real pixel in images to match the flutter pixel